# how to make bill in php and sql

Tags: php, mysql

i have online shop and i have problem making the Bill for each order

let say someone buy 2 t-shart and 1 shoes it will add to the trolley table wich have prodcutid , usreid , Quantity , now if the user confirm the order how can i create bill with all the item he buy and save it to new database named bills

note that same user may have diffrent bill with different item

this is the code that display the orders and the total price

```js
function CallMyOrder($identificador)
{
 
 global $database_connectoos, $connectoos;
mysql_select_db($database_connectoos, $connectoos);
$query_CoryFuncion = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tbltrolley WHERE idUser = %s AND tbltrolley.intOrderDone = 1 , $identificador);
$CoryFuncion = mysql_query($query_CoryFuncion, $connectoos) or die(mysql_error());
$row_CoryFuncion = mysql_fetch_assoc($CoryFuncion);
$totalRows_CoryFuncion = mysql_num_rows($CoryFuncion);
?>
<?php
 if ($totalRows_CoryFuncion > 0) { // Show if recordset not empty 
echo " <li>  User : &nbsp;".CallUserName($row_CoryFuncion['idUser']);
$totalPrice =0;
 $pricemultnumber;

do {
 $pricemultnumber = $row_CoryFuncion['intQuantity'] * CallProductPrice($row_CoryFuncion['idProduct']);
 
echo "<li><br>";
echo "<img src='../document/product/".CallProductImage($row_CoryFuncion['idProduct'])."' border='0'/>";    
echo "Product Name : &nbsp;".CallProductName($row_CoryFuncion['idProduct']);
echo "<br>";
echo "Quantity : &nbsp;".$row_CoryFuncion['intQuantity'];
echo "<br>";
echo "Price : ".$pricemultnumber." RM";
echo "<br></li>";

$totalPrice = $totalPrice + $pricemultnumber;


} while ($row_CoryFuncion = mysql_fetch_assoc($CoryFuncion));
echo "<br>";
echo "<p style='font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;'>Tax : ".CallTax()."</p>";

              $multp = (100 + CallTax())/100;
     $totalPrice = $totalPrice * $multp;
 
echo "<p style='font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;'>Total Price = ".$totalPrice." RM</p>";

 
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: am just trying to build the website first after that i will see the security problems , and thanks for the information i will make sure to go throw everything you  suggest

Comment: Security problems are just part of the issue here. Learning how to use prepared statements with placeholder values properly eliminates almost all of your escaping mistakes so you won't waste time tracking down syntax errors. If you do it right the first time you'll save considerable amounts of frustration later.

Comment: ok will do , but now i hope i can find ans for my question